# How to extract vectors of consecutive numbers?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that I have a Q vector which is defined as `Q = [1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 15];` and I would like to find a way to extract different vectors of consecutive numbers and also a vector for the rest of the elements. So my result would be like:

```
q1 = [1 2 3 4 5];
q2 = [8 9 10 ];
q3 = [15];
```

Comment: The `diff` function may be your friend.

Comment: I have tried diff function but the results are not the ones that I am looking for. and the diff function will give all of the consecutive numbers in a unique vector.

Comment: show your code what you have tried

Comment: Is your vector `Q` always going to be monotonically increasing? Can the numbers be repeated? Why is `Q` a cell array instead of a normal vector?

Comment: its always increasing monotonically. and no negative integer is included. there is no chance of repitition. Suppose Q is a normal vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `diff`, `cumsum` and [`accumarray`:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
q = accumarray(cumsum([1, diff(Q)~=1])', Q', [], @(x){x})
```

which returns:

```
{[1,2,3,4,5];
 [8,9,10];
 [15]}
```

i.e. `q{1}` gives you `[1,2,3,4,5]` etc which is a far cleaner solution to having separately named vectors. But if you really really wanted to have them, and you know exactly how many groups you will get out, you can do it as follows:

```
[q1,q2,q3] = q{:};
```

Explanation:

`accumarray` will apply an aggregation function (4th input) to elements of a vector (2nd input) based on groupings specified in another vector (1st input).

To use the notation in the docs:

```
sub = cumsum([1, diff(Q)~=1])';
val = Q';
fun = @(x){x};
```

Note that `sub` needs to start from `1`. The idea is to use `diff` to find elements that are consecutive (i.e. where `Q(i+1) - Q(i) == 1`) which is vectorized using the `diff` function. By specifying `diff(Q)~=1` we can find the breaks between groups of consecutive numbers (concatenating the `1` at the beginning to force a break at the start). `cumsum` then just converts these breaks into vector of in the right form for `sub` i.e.

```
sub = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3]
```

The aggregation function we specify is just cell concatenation.

Comment: I got this : Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.

Comment: @MsenRezaee sorry left off transposes. See the edit (i.e. added in the `'`s)

Comment: This code just make it more complicated. The result is concentrated in a larger vector not in seprated vectors. This is the result I got:ans = 

    [ 1]
    [ 2]
    [ 3]
    [ 4]
    [ 5]
    []
    []
    [ 8]
    [ 9]
    [10]
    []
    []
    []
    []
    [15]

Comment: @MsenRezaee Why would you want separate vectors? That will most certainly make your code more complicated. This way you can get any of the vectors by calling `q{1}` instead of `q1`. You want it this way, you don't want separately named vectors. They will be very cumbersome to work with. But if you really want to split this up (which you don't) then call `q{:}`.

Comment: I am in the middle of another bigger code, and in this part of this code I need seprated vectors. thanks by the way

Comment: @MsenRezaee unless you know you are getting the same number of groups every time, separate vectors will make your code bad. If you think you need them, more likely you need to refactor your code. A cell array like this is almost 100% the right solution for you.

Comment: but I am not even getting the result that you have mentioned, I am just obtaing all of my scalars in different vectors. as I pasted it here for you. if I get the result of {[1,2,3,4,5];
 [8,9,10];
 [15]}. that would solve everything and I will be very thankful

Comment: Oh sorry, another typo, I left off the `~=1`. Try the latest edit

Comment: @Dan, about your advice of using cell array and not different vectors- the general idea really makes sense, but what would you do if you want to preserve the meaning of each vector, by appropriate name, for example? add another column to the cell array?

Comment: @Adiel Either that or use a `struct`